# Spring JPA: Unexpected rollback exception hides the actual exception I need to handle

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am experimenting with `@transactional` in spring boot. I have written a service with multiple table insertions and I want the entire thing to rollback if there is any exception.
This works fine but rather than throwing the actual exception that caused the rollback, I am getting `Unexpected Rollback Exception`

```
@transactional
public void insertIntoTables(){
    repositoryone.save(new Table1());
    repositorytwo.save(new Table2()); //expecting data integrity violation exception on this line
}
```

Rather than throwing the `DataIntegrityViolationException`, the above code throws `Unexpected Rollback Exception`. I want the rollback to happen ofcourse, just want to avoid the exception so that I can use the actual one.
How to get the actual exception for handling purposes?

Comment: Where are you throwing a `DataIntegrityViolationException`? If you would like that to be thrown instead of `UnexpectedRollbackException`, then surround the `save` method with a `try-catch` block, catch the `UnexpectedRollbackException`, and throw the exception you'd like to throw instead.

Comment: That is because the exception happens during the commit. If you want to trigger constraint checks before the commit then do a `saveAndFlush` (assuming you are extending `JpaRepository` for your repositories) or directly call `flush` on the `EntityManager`. Thatt will trigger state sync with the database before the commit and will get you another `DataAccessException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I faced similar issue before. I handled it by adding rollback for. Below is how I handled it.

1. Imported org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
2. Then instead of @Transactional, I used @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class) above my service methods

This will handle any runtime exception. So, DataIntegrityViolationException should be displayed to user.